# Hide price and add to basket for guests

Tags: magento-1.9, price, if

I'd like to ***hide the price and add to cart button for guests*** not logged in to my Magento site. I'd also like to show a ***'login or register to view prices'*** message for guests too.

I imagine this will be an if statement within price.phtml but I'm not sure exactly how to implement this. Can anyone please provide a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/hide-price-and-add-to-cart-for-guests-users.html, i think is what you want.

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE and thanks for answering the question. Please note that to make things look better you can use custom link like so : `[my link words](http://the-actual-link)`